# How to enable Full Text Search (FTS) in sugarcrm Community editiion 6.5.14?

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, sugarcrm

I'm using sugarcrm Community Edition 6.5.14. I tried to enable FTS on custom modules. 
I've done related searches on sugarcrm forums/googled.

I'm unable to find the suitable free step by step guide or packages to full fill my requirement.

I tried using Elastic search module. I built the module

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIuObWJ2S8U

But I'm not close enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your interest in SugarCRM.
ElasticSearch feature available in paid version of SugarCRM only. The video you pointed out is for third party module called SugarCRM Advanced Search.

P.S. I'm one of the developers of SugarCRM.